# Поиск меньшего списка в большем. Аналог str.find для списков. (python)

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, поиск, список

Есть два списка: a и b.
Требуется проверить вхождение a в b и выдать индекс первого элемента.
Если a в b не обнаружен вернуть -1
Например:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [4, 5, 6]
#вернёт 3

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [4, 6, 5]
#вернёт -1
```

Я не могу использовать библиотеки кроме стандартных, идущих вместе с пайтоном.

---

Извините, написал непонятно.
Мне нужно не посчитать количество вхождений.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
         [4, 5, 6]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы функция подставила один список к другому и нашла индекс первого элемента a в b (В данном случае элемента 4 под третьим индексом)

Comment: Пробовали что-то писать или искать перед заданием вопроса? Добавьте это в вопрос с помощью кнопки править

Comment: А числа в `a` не повторяются? И заведомо отсортированы? Или это только такой пример?

Comment: Имейте в виду, что вопросы несоответствующий правилам подлежат закрытию и удалению. Ваш вопрос не соответствует, так содержит только задание и по сути является попыткой решить задачу чужими руками.

Comment: Если списки могут быть неупорядоченными, то это задача на поиск подмассива в массиве.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [4, 5, 6]
if len(a) <= len(b):
    for i in range(0, len(b) - len(a)):
        if b[i:i+len(a)] == a:
            print(b.index(a[0]))
            exit()
print(-1)
```

Comment: Для второго примера возвращает 3, а должно быть -1

Comment: Так они одинаковые в вопросе) там нужно а и b  местами поменять наверное

Comment: чем? b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
         b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Я имею в виду в вопросе. У вас почему-то наоборот сделано

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что они в вопросе одинаковые. Ошибся человек. По условию же понятно.

Comment: `a = [4, 5, 6]` vs `a = [4, 6, 5]`

Comment: Ну так это a, a вы мне про b. Теперь понятно, что нужно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112969/discussion-between-romanr-and-dim0n).

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [4, 6, 5]


def finder(list_a, list_b):
    r = []
    for i in list_a:
        if i in list_b:
            r.append(list_b.index(i))
    if Len(r) == 0:
        return -1
    return r
    
print(finder(list_a=a, list_b=b))
```

Answer (score -1):

Кажется никто не понял, что мне нужно, но задача оказалась гораздо легче чем я думал, и я оставлю здесь рабочий код)

```
def find(b, a):
    first = b.index(a[0])
    result = True
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if not a[i] == b[i+first]:
            result = False
            break
    if not result:
        return -1
    return first
```

Comment: Ну то есть числа в большем списке как минимум уникальны. Иначе такой алгоритм бы не всегда был правильным.

Comment: Для списков с не уникальными числами можно перебрать все места потенциального начала большего списка.

Comment: Именно так. Алгоритм уже другой несколько будет.

Comment: Если ваш алгоритм работает только с уникальными числами, то это не аналог `str.find()`, как было сказано в теме вопроса. `str.find()` ищет произвольную подстроку в произвольной строке.

Comment: `def find(b, a):
    firsts = [i for i, x in enumerate(b) if x == a[0]]
    result = True
    for first in firsts:
        for i in range(1, len(a)):
            if not a[i] == b[i+first]:
                result = False
                break
        if result == False:
            firsts.remove(first)
    return firsts`
Вот этот уже работает не только с уникальными и возвращает список всех вариантов первых индексов.